# Python Scrapy: How to close cluster's logging

Tags: python, scrapy, hierarchical-clustering

I use cluster.HierarchicalClustering in the Scrapy but there are too much logging in the console. How can I close the cluster's log but I don't want  to use '--nolog' to close all the logging.

I tried to set LOG_LEVEL= 'INFO' in my Scrapy settings.py and it appeared other logging.

There is my code about cluster, if you have any way, please help me.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from cluster import HierarchicalClustering


def distance(url1, url2):
    ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, url1, url2).ratio()
    return 1.0 - ratio

def urls_clustering(urls):
    hc = HierarchicalClustering(urls, distance)
    clusters = hc.getlevel(0.2)
    # pprint.pprint(clusters)

    return clusters
```

And there are the logging:

```
2017-06-29 13:48:29 [cluster.matrix] DEBUG: Generating row 159/203 (78.33%)
2017-06-29 13:48:29 [cluster.matrix] DEBUG: Generating row 160/203 (78.82%)
2017-06-29 13:48:29 [cluster.matrix] DEBUG: Generating row 161/203 (79.31%)
2017-06-29 13:48:29 [cluster.matrix] DEBUG: Generating row 162/203 (79.80%)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried good ol' python's `logging`?

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('cluster.matrix').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: I add the code to settings.py and it works! Thank you !